# PMT error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a user Form to input data for a model. I want to calculate the monthly payments needed for a loan using the PMT function in VBA. I need this so I can then take the value and add it to the total monthly expenses. I have provided a screen shot of the current code I have written. each time I run the macro I get "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" I have tried a few different ways to calculate this, but I would really like the payment inputs to come from the user form since I will have many different inputs.

Just to clarify the "Val(txt_Loan-Amount)" are the reference to the user form I have already created and named each input box with the names to pull the data from.

I have tried this by manually added the number in and it does calculate the payment. I'm assuming the error is coming from the user form values

```
Dim FVal, PVal, APR, TotPmts, Payment
FVal = 0    ' Usually 0 for a loan.
PVal = Val(Txt_Loan_Amount)
APR = Val(Txt_Interest_Rate)
If APR > 1 Then APR = APR / 100    ' Ensure proper form.
TotPmts = Val(Txt_Amortized) * 12
MsgBox "Your payment will be " & Format(Payment) & " per month."
```

Like I mentioned above the error I am receiving is "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: I think you left out the `Payment` calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 1 line IF/Then statements.  As stated, all your variables are `Variant`.  If you enter the `WorksheetFunction.Pmt` command, it will tell you what your variables should be, i.e. Arg1 as Double, Arg2 as Double.  Your variables should match.  You can test your inputs on your user form to ensure they are compliant.  After you determine that your APR is > or < 1, you will want to convert to a monthly rate as you are converting your time periods to monthly.  In formatting the `Payment`, I put a minus sign in front to display as a positive number.

```
Dim PVal As Double
Dim APR As Double
Dim TotPmts As Double
Dim Payment As Double

PVal = Val(Txt_Loan_Amount) 'Based on input
APR = Val(Txt_Interest_Rate) 'Based on input
If APR > 1 Then APR = APR / 100    ' Ensure proper form.
APR = APR / 12 'Convert to monthly
TotPmts = Val(Txt_Amortized) * 12 'Using monthly
Payment = WorksheetFunction.Pmt(APR, TotPmts, PVal)

MsgBox "Your payment will be " & Format(-Payment, "$#,##0.00") & " per month."
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! You solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Hi it seems you never ended your `If` statement with `End If`. It wasn't 100% clear where the end if belonged but I put it where I figured you wanted it.

Also your `Dim` statement is declaring your variables as `Variant` types, so you may also want to declare these accordingly since it may be causing your error as well.

Good coding practice is would indent as well. I did some basics below, it makes it easier to read, follow and maintain, but it won't solve your issues.

Try the below

```
Dim FVal, PVal, APR, TotPmts, Payment

FVal = 0    ' Usually 0 for a loan.
PVal = Val(Txt_Loan_Amount)
APR = Val(Txt_Interest_Rate)

If APR > 1 Then 
    APR = APR / 100    ' Ensure proper form.
End If 'Please note I put this where I thought it belonged, you may need to move this.
TotPmts = Val(Txt_Amortized) * 12

MsgBox "Your payment will be " & Format(Payment) & " per month."
```